# prevent blur on content editable element on clicking a specific element (angular)

Tags: angular

Heres the stackblitz with my example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nopkp

Id like to prevent blurring on the button click only (and keep all default bluring behavior such as clicking outside of the content editable `p`)

Seems like the button click blurs it instantaneously so my attempts to add conditionals have failed (as you can see in the loom)

note: I guess I'm not technically preventing blur (since I want to keep the default blur intact), I just want to prevent some logic from happening on clicking that element. I've set it up in the loom the way I want it to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `(click)` event with `(mousedown)` should do the trick for you:

```
<h1 (mousedown)="itemClick()">dont blur (click me)</h1>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o8am7m?file=src/app/app.component.html)**